# Edge flicker when moving Camera (2D)

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, spritebatch

I have a Orthographic camera. I have a fixed landscape texture and a texture for a moveable object. 
If the object moves to the right the camera will also move with the object.

When I also draw an score text that should have fixed position on the screen, that score text position will be update too if the camera's position gets updated so that it looks like that it is fixed on the screen. But if I do that, I have some edge flickering at the text object. I'am using SpriteBatch!

Is there another approach to implement a fixed positioned object on the screen?

Comment: Ok, I only had to create a second spritebatch for the score text.

Comment: is this for computers or phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only hat to set a filter for the texture.

Pseudo:
texture.setFilter(Linera_Filter, Linear_Filter)